# Interview function with time complexity

Tags: c#, time-complexity

I had an interview question to write a program in C# that Outputs odd number of occurrences in an array.

**Example:** [2, 2, 3, 3, 3] => [3] (Considering the array is sorted)

**My solution was:**

```
public list<int> OddOccurance(list<int> InputList)
{
    list<int> output = new list<int>();

    for(int i=0; i<InputList.length; i++)
    {
        int Count = 0;

        for(int j=1; j<(InputList.length-1); j++)
        {
            if(InputList[i] == InputList[j])
            {
                Count++;
            }
        }

        if(Count % 2 != 0)
        { 
            output.add(InputList[i]);
        }
    }

    return output.distinct();
}
```

I am thinking the answer is correct only but the interviewer had asked me like different ways of how I can make the solution much faster.

Can anyone please tell me the time complexity of the above solution please.

If there is a way to make the above solution much faster then what can be the time complexity of that solution.

Comment: @Rocky, maybe try asking at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Its Big O notation aka time complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: Can't _you_ think of any other solution than nested loops? Like keeping a count of each number you encountered somehow?

Comment: Is the input array *guaranteed* to be sorted?

Comment: *If* you post this to Code Review, make sure that you post ***real**, working, actual code*.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Note that having sorted/unsorted input won't affect the Big O of a good solution.  (You can get O(n) pretty trivially in an unsorted set, and you provably can't do better than O(n) under any circumstances.)  The sorted version would likely be quicker, but not on the scale of Big O

Comment: @TimothyShields It needs to return items that are repeated in the list an odd number of times, not items that are themselves odd.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I first thought that if the array was unsorted, I would start of sorting it, but indeed an O(n) solution is still possible, but the state space required in the method increases from O(1) to O(n).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Well, it'd go up to O(m), where m is the number of distinct items, and 0 <= m <= n.  But yes, the space complexity would go up if the data wasn't sorted and you wanted O(n) speed.

Comment: @Servy O(m) = O(n), AFAIK. I mean, linear is still linear. But of course m !== n.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It depends.  For example, if I told you that I had a list of items of arbitrary size, but all of the items are random integers between 0 and 10, then O(m) and O(n) are radically different from each other.  Of course, if no constraints are provided, then O(m) = O(n).  It's just worthwhile to recognize that while it's *possible* for the problem space to have both numbers scale to infinity, it's also possible for one to scale infinitely and one to not.

Comment: As @Servy pointed out restircions on array's content can significantly change best result. I.e. if array is sorted and you know number of distinct numbers (m) or upper/lower boundary shows small variety (like range is -m,m), one can go for O(m * log n) solution assuming m (number of distinct items) is significantly less than n ( should be at least less than n/log n).

Answer (score 1):

The root problem of your solution is seen on this line:

```
return output.Distinct();
```

The very fact that you are doing a `Distinct` means that you may be adding more entries than you should.

So how can you optimize it? Observe that since the array is sorted, the only place where you can find a number that's the same as the one you're looking at is next to it, or next to another number that's equal to your current number. In other words, your numbers go in "runs".

This observation lets you go from two nested loops and an O(N<sup>2</sup>) solution to a single loop and an O(N) solution. Simply walk the array, and check lengths of each "run": when you see a new number, store its index. If you come across a new number, see if the length of the "run" is odd, and start a new run:

```
int start = 0;
int pos = 1;
while (pos < InputList.Length) {
    if (InputList[pos] != InputList[start]) {
        if ((pos-start) % 2 == 1) {
            output.Add(InputList[start]);
        }
        start = pos;
    }
    pos++;
}
// Process the last run
if ((InputList.Length-start) % 2 == 1) {
    output.Add(InputList[start]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/E0xhQs)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is `O(n^2)` - if you don't know why - evaluate sum:

[image]

This is an equation which describes the running time of your algorithm. You can solve it in linear time easily - just increment `i` instead of inner loop over all values in array.

```
for (int i=0; i<InputList.Length; ++i)
{
    int currentValue = InputList[i];
    int j=i+1;
    int count = 1;

     while (InputList[j] == currentValue && j<InputList.Length)
     {
        count++;
         i++;
         j++;
     }

     if (count % 2 == 0) 
        ..
}
```

If array is not sorted - use dictionary (hash table - Dictionary in C#) - value is a dictionary key, count is a dictionary value. (that will give you Contains key check in `O(1)`) Another way to get linear time if implemented properly.